# Module waffle.jna not found, required by org.mariadb.jdbc

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

I doing my first JDBC project with javaFX

```
module com.example.obs {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.mariadb.jdbc;

    opens com.example.obs to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.obs;
}
```

I'm getting this exception

> java: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Module waffle.jna not found, required by org.mariadb.jdbc

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the MariaDB JDBC driver has a dependency on the Waffle JNA (Java Native Access) library.

To get rid of this error you need add the waffle.jna library to your `module-info.java` file:

```java
requires waffle.jna
```

Or include the library to your `pom.xml` if you are using Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.waffle</groupId>
    <artifactId>waffle-jna</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're using Gradle add it to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  implementation group: 'com.github.waffle', name: 'waffle-jna', version: '3.2.0'
}
```

If you're using java eclipse u can add it to the `.classpath` file

```xml
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/path/to/waffle-jna-3.2.0.jar"/>
```

You can download the jar file [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.waffle/waffle-jna/3.2.0)

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me.  The module path is different than the classpath, so why put a module on the classpath in the Eclipse configuration? (I don’t know Eclipse, maybe this is how it works with modules, but it seems wrong).

Comment: In the answer it says to either add a maven dependency or require the module in the module-info. But are not both things required for a true modular application?

Comment: If mariadb requires the jna module, and if you have a maven dependency on mariadb and also require mariadb in your module-info, shouldn’t both the maven dependency on waffle and its module requirement be transitively picked up automatically? If not, does that mean that the mariadb maven pom or module-info is broken and should be fixed?